# How can I tell pylint that a variable will be defined at run time?

Tags: python, python-decorators, pylint

**Short version:** If I define a decorator to import a module at run time and declare it in the `func_globals` for a method, how can I tell Pylint that the resulting variable has been defined?

**Long version:** Consider the following example:

```py
from importlib import import_module

def with_import(module):
    modname = module.split('.')[-1]
    def decorate(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            func.func_globals[modname] = import_module(module)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorate

@with_import('numpy')
def create_array(n):
    return numpy.empty(n)

print(create_array(5))
```

This code works just fine since the `with_import` decorator declares `numpy` for the `create_array` function. However, when I run PyLint I see

```py
E: 16,11: Undefined variable 'numpy' (undefined-variable)
```

Is there a way to tell Pylint that this variable will in fact be defined at run time? I don't really want to disable the `unused-variable` check for the whole module in case someone actually declares a regular unused variable at a later date.

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing this? It's really not very nice.

Comment: The `with_import` decorator is used in a production module to import an optional dependency at runtime with a nice error message that references the calling function. I could have put that into a function instead and call it on the first line of the relevant method, but a decorator seemed more elegant (at the time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable checks on a block or line basis, for example

```
def f():
    # pylint: disable=E0602
    x[0] = 5
    y[0] = 5
# No errors

def f():
    x[0] = 5 # pylint: disable=E0602
    y[0] = 5
# Only y will raise the undefined variable error
```

With decorators you have an equivalent to the first one, I was actually surprised it works, and thinks it's quite ugly but:

```
@deco
# pylint: disable=E0602
def f():
    x[0] = 5 # No error here
y[0] = 5 # Error here
```

Note you'll have a `I: Locally disabling undefined-variable (E0602)` in the pylint report

Comment: Unfortunately, this will disable warnings for all undefined variables.  Ideally there would be a way to disable warnings for a specific variable.

Answer (score 3):

pylint pays attention to `typing.TYPE_CHECKING`. So you can do:

```py
import typing
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import numpy

@with_import('numpy')
def create_array(n):
    return numpy.empty(n)
```

`typing.TYPE_CHECKING` is always false at runtime, so the import doesn't get run. However, pylint assumes `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` to be true and will analyse the code as if the import had been performed.

Answer (score 2):

What if your decorator supplies such modules as parameters to your function?

Here's a working example:

```
from importlib import import_module

def with_import(module):
    modname = module.split('.')[-1]
    def decorate(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            obj = import_module(module)
            func.func_globals[modname] = obj
            # merge modname=obj with kwargs
            return func(*args, **dict({modname: obj}, **kwargs))
        return wrapper
    return decorate

@with_import('numpy')
def create_array(n, numpy):
    # module available here and nobody complains
    return numpy.empty(n)

print create_array(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable it only for the exact line it happens:

```
@with_import('numpy')
def create_array(n):
    return numpy.empty(n) # pylint: disable=undefined-variable
```